# Converting date row to column for last N days

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by, row

I want to build a time series prediction model using features such as week of the year, day of the week, season, etc.

Since the prediction will be highly affected by the most recent values, I want to use the values in the last 5 days, as features, however I am having trouble with data preparation for learning:

My current table looks like this:

```
    date        id  score
0   2014-01-01  A   75
1   2014-01-01  B   1
2   2014-01-01  C   2
4   2014-01-02  A   84
5   2014-01-02  B   1
6   2014-01-02  C   3
8   2014-01-03  A   1
9   2014-01-03  B   1
10  2014-01-03  C   1
```

So I want each row to look like this:

```
    date        id  score  date_1 date_2 date_3 date_4 date-5
10  2014-01-03  A   1      84     75     0      0      0 
 9  2014-01-03  B   1      1      1      0      0      0
```

Date_1 is the score of A, the day before its date on 'date' column, date_2 is two days before, and so on...

So that I can predict the next day, using the information of last 5 days and more features that are irrelevant to this question.
It is OK to fill NaN values with 0

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby(id)` and `shift`. You should have your df be sorted by date: `df.sort_values('date')` before using the following command:

```
for i in range(5):
    df['date_'+str(i+1)] = df.groupby('id')['score'].shift(i+1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Using the above command yields the following df:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer - see below example of shifting using timedelta.

Comment: That works fast and smooth thank you. It will be possible to implement this if I can fill the missing dates for every product id with 0s. Do you have an idea to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Time shifting using Timedelta**

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53856859/5447172) is shifting by numeric index. Works in this instance, but it will break if there are gaps in the dates, or if the dates have not been sorted.

You can handle this by converting the DataFrame to a time series, then using the `freq` parameter of `DataFrame.shift()` with a `pandas.Timedelta` object.

Example data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2014-01-01'] * 3 +
                           ['2014-01-02'] * 3 +
                           ['2014-01-03'] * 3,
                   'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 3,
                   'score': [75, 1, 2, 84, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1]})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

The IDs mean we need a couple of loops to keep everything separate:

```
for i in range(5):
    for id in df.id.unique():
        col = 'date_{}'.format(i+1)
        freq = pd.Timedelta('{}d'.format(i+1))
        df.loc[df.id==id, col] = df.loc[df.id==id, 'score'].shift(freq=freq)
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This produces same output as other approach on this example, but if you have a skip in the date it will be different.

Output:

```
           id  score  date_1  date_2  date_3  date_4  date_5
date                                                        
2014-01-01  A     75       0       0       0       0       0
2014-01-01  B      1       0       0       0       0       0
2014-01-01  C      2       0       0       0       0       0
2014-01-02  A     84      75       0       0       0       0
2014-01-02  B      1       1       0       0       0       0
2014-01-02  C      3       2       0       0       0       0
2014-01-03  A      1      84      75       0       0       0
2014-01-03  B      1       1       1       0       0       0
2014-01-03  C      1       3       2       0       0       0
```

Comment: Thank you for the generalized answer because yes there are gaps in dates and dates do not have to be sorted by index so that's a good vision from you.
However when I ran the exact code with full table, I got the error : "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Comment: Is there any way you can share all the data in the question, or a larger extract of it? This worked fine for me based on the example data I created, but it's always easier to answer if we're both working with same data to begin with.

Comment: It sounds like you probably have duplicate date + id pairs in your full table (e.g. multiple entries for A on the same date). That's beyond the scope of the question, but would be fixed with a `.drop_duplicates(['date', 'id'])` before you make `'date'` into the index (or you may need to do a `.groupby(['date', 'id']).score.sum()`, depending on the cause of the problem. Politely ask that you upvote and approve this answer if this does solve your problem, as I think it's a safer solution than using numeric indexing.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I tried but dropping duplicates and groupby.sum but neither worked out. The error is still the same.
Here's the full dataset:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/05dc9e1c1cebd59f07a6dea954f5920b20181220104423/0c6b9b

Comment: `drop_duplicates()` fixes the error, as you have duplicated date/id pairs in your dataset. I suspect you haven't executed drop_duplicates correctly. After you load the DataFrame, run `df.drop_duplicates(['date', 'id'], inplace=True)` and then all the code will run correctly.